# How do I convert button code from HTML to HAML?

Tags: html, ruby, button, haml

I'm new to the Rails framework and my boss tells me that I need to code in HAML rather then HTML, so I'm stuck trying to figure out how to convert my html.erb to HAML code. My problem is that I have the following code for a button:

```
   <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
```

This button adds the product to a line item, can anyone suggest how to write the above code in HAML?

Comment: That isn't HTML. As far as I can tell with half a minute's Googling:  It is Ruby ERB (a template language).

Comment: HAML really is quite simple to get started with. Have you looked at the [reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html)? Or maybe even just the [tutorial](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html). That got me started real quick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product)
```

I went through one of my Rails apps a couple weeks ago and converted it to HAML, and it seems to me that's all I needed to do to fix those sort of things.

Comment: Yeah..for HAML, the erb code are same, just give `-` for `<% %>`code and give `=` for `<%= %>` code. It is the HTML part that has got much changes in HAML..[link](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html)

Comment: Converting from HTML to HAML is mostly throwing away closing tags and making sure the nesting is correct. I use HAML for all my Sinatra stuff often but this was my first time using it with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

`This = button_to` generates an input `<type=button>` not a `<button>`.